# Does exists an equivalent of `ecdf(x)(x)` of R in python?

Tags: r, python, scikit-learn, scipy

I am struggling to find an equivalent of ecdf function of R, namely

```
x<-1:10
y<-ecdf(x)(x)
```

in Python. Does exists an equivalent of this function?

Comment: this http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.ECDF.html?

Comment: Thanx. Please, put your comment as answer.

Comment: Questions about software are generally off topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you're looking for this http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.ECDF.html.

Answer (score 1):

Toby's suggestion to use the `ECDF` class in statsmodels is great.  Here's an alternative that you could use if you don't want the dependency on statsmodels, but scipy is OK:

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata

y = rankdata(x, method='max')/float(len(x))
```

Comment: Such an elegant solution. Thank you.